# Give an Argb Value an integer value

Tags: c#

I am trying to write some code which will allow me to pass in an image (heat map) and return me a 2d array which I can put into excel for quantitative analysis. I can create a 2d array of Argb values, representing each pixel however I am trying to create a scaler equivalent values. The current code I am using won't work with my code due the variation in Argb values (it isn't a true heat map);

```
public static class ColorBGRToScalarConverter
{
    private static int MarginOfError;

    public static int Convert(Color input)
    {

        int r = input.R;
        int g = input.G;
        int b = input.B;

        var min = new[] { r, g, b }.ToList().Min();

        if (b - 240 > 0 && r != 0)
        {
            MarginOfError += r;
            r = 0;
        }


        // Handle errant values from JPG artifacts/blur/anti-aliasing or margin of error

        if (r == min)
        {
            r = 0;
        }
        if (g == min)
        {
            g = 0;
        }
        if (b == min)
        {
            b = 0;
        }

       // Console.WriteLine($@"Margin of error is {MarginOfError}");

        if (b == 255 && r == 0)
        {
            return g;
        }
        else if (g == 255 && r == 0)
        {
            return 255 - b + 255;
        }
        else if (b == 0 && g == 255)
        {
            return 511 + r;
        }
        else if (b == 0 && r == 255)
        {
            return 255 - g + 766;
        }
        else if (b == 0 && g == 0 && r != 0)
        {
            return 1023 + r;
        }


        throw new Exception("I should have found a value.");
    }
}
}
```

Is there a similar process I can use create a colour representative of an integer on a scale (e.g 0 - 1279) for red - blue.

Comment: FYI you don't need the `ToList` before the `Min`.

Comment: What are you wanting to do? Are you wanting to e.g. convert to an HSV color space and then take the S values? You need to decide how to flatten the color space.

Comment: what goes wrong?